# How to provide immediate feedback if save action button is clicked in jqgrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

Edit action button is added to jqGrid row using code below.
After editing if Save action button is clicked, nothing happens, Save button remains active.
Save takes some time and it looks like click is ignored. Users clicks save button again and again.

How to provide immediate feedback after Save button is clicked and before save is finished: change save button icon to saving animation, remove possibility to click it again, show saving message ?
jqueryUI is used.

```
colModel: [{"fixed":true,"label":" change ","name":"_actions","width":($.browser.webkit == true? 37+15: 32+15)
    ,"align":"center","sortable":false,"formatter":"actions",
"formatoptions":{"keys":true,"delbutton":false,"onSuccess":function (jqXHR) {actionresponse = jqXHR;return true;}
    ,"afterSave":function (rowID) {
    cancelEditing($('#grid'));afterRowSave(rowID,actionresponse);actionresponse=null; }
    ,"onEdit":function (rowID) {
      if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
        cancelEditing($('#grid'));
        lastSelectedRow = rowID;
        }
    }}
```

**Update**

FireFox makes grid inactive (grays out) properly if saved in both ways in inline edit without any code. So it seems like IE issue.

How to gray out jqGrid in IE 9 also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct your problem is not problem of 'actions' formatter. The same problem you have in inline editing if the user just press "Enter" and the row should be saved on the server. There are **no** direct event which will be fire before the `ajax` request to the server.

Nevertheless there are different *indirect* possibilities to receive control and to display the "Saving..." message for the user. The simplest way is to use `serializeRowData` to display the message. You should not forget to close the "Saving..." div in both `errorfunc` and `successfunc` methods.

Comment: thank you. I updated question about implementing FF behaviour in IE. Maybe it is possible to use it. I also tried to use stadard jqUery ajax show/hide  events by method to those properties using ajaxOptions in to `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults` but those events are not fired.

Comment: @Andrus: You asked in your question to provide "immediate feedback" for some kind of "saving animation". It's not the same as with `loadui: "block"`. You should examine your code for some manipulation with `"#lui_"+$t.p.id` div which you could do.

Comment: I'm sorry for unclear question. I added better question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333943/how-to-gray-out-jqgrid-in-save-in-inline-edit-in-ie-like-firefox-does .