# how to gray out jqgrid in save in inline edit in IE like Firefox does

Tags: jqgrid

If row is saved in inline edit in jqGrid, FireFox makes grid dim ( grayd out) during save operation.

Internet Explorer 9 does not change grid appearance.

loadui parameter is not used so it should have its default value (enabled).
If grid is refreshed, it is not grayed out in both browsers as expected.
Gray out occurs during save in FireFox only.

How to gray out grid in save (if edit url is called) in Internet Explorer 9 also?

**Update**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
2. Select

Functionality (4.0) new

Formatter actions

1. Click in edit action button
2. Click in save action button

Observed:

In FireFox click in save button makes grid darker for a while
In IE 9  click in save button does not change grid.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. On my test sites during saving of inline editing row the gray overlay will be set over the grid. The same behavior exist in IE9.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you. I updated question and provided steps to reproduce

Comment: @Oleg: this demo page has also another issue: rapidly clicking in edit/save action buttons in multiple rows puts multiple rows into edit mode. In my application I have similar issue if multiselect is used which resets selection. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analysed the problem. The reason is [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L226) used in the inline editing:

```
async : false, //?!?
```

(the comment "?!?" is the original comment in jqGrid code). So in general the overlay which block the grid will be shown at the beginning of the `jQuery.ajax` request which save the row, but because of `async : false` the GUI of the web browser will be *blocked till the completion*. In the `complete` event handle the overlay will be hidden and the user can't see anything. All web browsers excepting Firefox don't show the overlay.

To fix the problem without changing of jqGrid code one can use ajaxRowOptions option of jqGrid. The option is documented not in [the common list of jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions), but at the end of the [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) documentation. The usage of

```
ajaxRowOptions: { async: true }
```

as the jqGrid option or as the new default option

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    ajaxRowOptions: { async: true }
});
```

will solve the problem in case of inline editing.

In case of usage of 'actions' formatter another problem from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L438) exist

```
if ( $('#'+gid).jqGrid('saveRow',rid,  op.onSuccess,op.url, op.extraparam, saverow, op.onError,restorerow) ) {
    $("tr#"+rid+" div.ui-inline-edit, "+"tr#"+rid+" div.ui-inline-del","#"+gid+ ".ui-jqgrid-btable:first").show();
    $("tr#"+rid+" div.ui-inline-save, "+"tr#"+rid+" div.ui-inline-cancel","#"+gid+ ".ui-jqgrid-btable:first").hide();
}
```

one can see that here jqGrid use the `saveRow` as really as asynchronous function here. If you will use `ajaxRowOptions: { async: true }` you will have to make divs `div.ui-inline-edit` and `div.ui-inline-del` visible and hide `div.ui-inline-save` and `div.ui-inline-cancel` inside of your `onSuccess` event handler.

**UPDATED**: Sorry another code of - the [saverow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L419) functions used as parameter of `saveRow` method do the same work. So I think all divs will be shown/hidden correctly without any additional code in your `onSuccess` event handler.

Comment: I reproduced multiple rows in inline edit issue mentioned in comment and posted it with complete local testcase in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344937/how-to-prevent-multiple-rows-in-edit-mode-in-range-selection-single-click-edit-jq